# Does the Gross-Hopkins period map have a natural interpretation coming from derived algebraic geometry?

Tags: homotopy-theory, etale-cohomology

The Gross-Hopkins period map is a map on the $W(k)$-points of $LT_n \to P^{n-1}$, where $k = F_{p^n}$. It sends a lift $G$ of the Honda formal group to the 1-$d$ subspace $\omega_G$ of the Dieudonn'e module $D(G)$ (which is a free $W(k)$-module of rank $n$). On the rigid-analytic level, the map is 'etale. Does the Gross-Hopkins period map have a natural interpretation coming from derived algebraic geometry? I suspect not.

If $X$ is a (proper) variety (over $C$, say) and $f$ is a meromorphic function on $X$, then the divisor $D$ associated to $f$ gives rise to a line bundle over $X$ (hence a finite map to projective space). What is the meromorphic function on the rigid generic fiber of Lubin-Tate space associated to the line bundle $\text{Lie}(G)$ (which, recall, determines the Gross-Hopkins map)?